How to access data in a vector of struct, accessed by a pointer
I am trying to create a vector in PSRAM on an ESP32-S3 with PSRAM enabled.  Here is my test code (using std=gnu++14).
I can: allocate some PSRAM memory, create a vector in the PSRAM, create a test record and add it to the vector and confirm the size goes up, delete records from the start of the vector and confirm the size goes down
But I can't work out how to read the vector data, see block in the middle commented out.
struct EventRecord_t { // owned by MESH_ROOT
    uint8_t  node = 0;
    uint8_t errorCount;
};

void eventsStart(){
    void* eventsRam;
    eventsRam = heap_caps_malloc(1000000, MALLOC_CAP_SPIRAM); // get memory from PSRAM
    std::vector<EventRecord_t>* eventStack; // declare pointer to vector of struct
    eventStack = (std::vector<EventRecord_t>*) eventsRam; // create vector in PSRAM
    EventRecord_t eventRecord; // create record entry and populate it
    eventRecord.node = 1;
    eventRecord.errorCount = 34;
    eventStack->push_back(eventRecord); // add record to eventstack 
    std::cout << "Size: " << eventStack->size() << std::endl; // confirm size is increasing
    eventRecord.node = 2;
    eventStack->push_back(eventRecord);
    std::cout << "Size: " << eventStack->size() << std::endl;
    eventRecord.node = 3;
    eventStack->push_back(eventRecord);
    std::cout << "Size: " << eventStack->size() << std::endl;

    // how to access eventStack data here;
    // eventRecord = eventStack[0];
    // uint8_t inode = eventStack[0]->node;

    eventStack->erase(eventStack->begin()); // delete first record from eventStack
    std::cout << "Size: " << eventStack->size() << std::endl; // confirm size is increasing
    eventStack->erase(eventStack->begin());
    std::cout << "Size: " << eventStack->size() << std::endl;
    eventStack->erase(eventStack->begin());
    std::cout << "Size: " << eventStack->size() << std::endl;
    free(eventsRam);
}

Output:
Size: 1
Size: 2
Size: 3
Size: 2
Size: 1
Size: 0


I believe that there are several problems with this. First, is that you are setting a pointer to a vector to a block of memory, but you never create a vector in that memory. attempting to use it as if it was a vector should be undefined behavior. What you would need for this is placement new to create a vector object in that memory. . . .

. . . Second is that a vector and its internally managed data store are two different things. Putting the vector in PSRAM has absolutely no impact on where the memory the vector uses for its storage of items comes from. To do that, you will have to create a vector that uses an allocator that provides memory from your block of PSRAM. You have to explicitly provide that allocator to the vector (one of its template parameters).

Completely agree with the two comments above. This code will not work unless you make the changes suggested there. However to answer the syntactic question, the simple approach would be eventStack->at(0) or if you want to use [] then (*eventStack)[0].

Thanks for your help.
"To do that, you will have to create a vector that uses an allocator that provides memory from your block of PSRAM. You have to explicitly provide that allocator to the vector (one of its template parameters)"
Could you give me sample code which does this

Handy reading After reading that, do a search through Stack Overflow for Writing Your Own Allocator. Tons of good material already out there.

Pretty complicated.  Struggling to find a matching example and I don't really understand the reference.  Most posts are about why you don't need an allocator.  Would really appreciate a sample for a vector of struct

If you were planning to use that memory block only for that one vector, I would be tempted to replace the std::vector with some sort of fixed capacity vector. In that specific, limited case, I would look at the external links at the bottom of this page for ideas. Sorry, I don't have a good generic allocator code example for you.

You need to write your own allocator
template <typename T>
class SPIRamAllocator {
public:
    using value_type = T;

    SPIRamAllocator() = default;

    template <typename U>
    constexpr SPIRamAllocator(const SPIRamAllocator<U>&) noexcept {}

    [[nodiscard]] T* allocate(std::size_t n) {
        // Allocate memory using heap_caps_malloc with MALLOC_CAP_SPIRAM
        T* ptr = static_cast<T*>(heap_caps_malloc(n * sizeof(T), MALLOC_CAP_SPIRAM));
        if (!ptr) {
            /* do something */
        }
        return ptr;
    }

    void deallocate(T* ptr, std::size_t) noexcept {
        // Free the allocated memory
        heap_caps_free(ptr);
    }
};

template <typename T, typename U>
bool operator==(const SPIRamAllocator<T>&, const SPIRamAllocator<U>&) {
    return true;
}

template <typename T, typename U>
bool operator!=(const SPIRamAllocator<T>&, const SPIRamAllocator<U>&) {
    return false;
}

and then you can use it:
std::vector<int, SpirAMAllocator<int>> vec;
std::vector<EventRecord_t, SpirAMAllocator<EventRecord_t>> vec;


This allocator is not too good, but it is just to show how to write them. You may want to provide max size for the vector, allocate in larger chunks or combine any other methods.

Thanks for giving me this.  I don't understand it yet but I have implemented it and it seems to work (although my original code also worked).
This gives me something to work with while I try to better understand it.
You gave me to examples of using the allocator right;  the first one for a vector of int, and the second for a vector of my struct?

I added some diagnostics to print the values of n and T in the SPIRamAllocator. I saw T = 2 which is the size of my struc (2 x uint8_t)  But when I added a uint32_t so my struct size is 6 (2 x uint8_t and a uint32_t) I saw my value of T changed to 8 which is a bit unexpected but I guess there is a reason for this?  I saw n goes up exponentially every time another record is appended.  When I pop records and then add more I see the memory is reused and SPIRamAllocator doesn't run.So I think its all working properly. I really appreciate you taking the time to help me with this.  Best regards

@ADL structs have padding. Trust your compiler

There is an alternative to managing the memory allocation destination for a single data structure. You can tell ESP IDF to allocate all heap memory above a given size from SPIRAM. According to section Provide External RAM via malloc() you need to configure two items in sdkconfig:

Set CONFIG_SPIRAM_USE to CONFIG_SPIRAM_USE_MALLOC
Configure the size limit which redirects the allocation from internal RAM to SPIRAM: CONFIG_SPIRAM_MALLOC_ALWAYSINTERNAL. E.g. I usually set it to 0 to allocate all heap memory from SPIRAM.

Note that there are situations where it's dangerous to allocate heap from SPIRAM. Most importantly thread stacks for FreeRTOS tasks that interact with (read data from or write to) Flash should be in internal RAM, otherwise they crash. If you create a task using the usual API call xTaskCreate() then you're fine because it allocates from internal RAM. If, however, you create your tasks using xTaskCreateStatic and give it a heap-allocated stack buffer, it's a danger zone. If the task writes to Flash, then make sure you allocate the stack buffer from internal RAM, not SPIRAM.

Thanks, this would be quite handy for me if it works ok.  But I have found that enabling PSRAM is causing other problems eg OTA over HTTPS start going slow and fails part way through. Even when I stop using PSRAM this is a problem, and disabling PSRAM fixes it again.  I set SPI RAM access method to "Make RAM allocatable using heap_caps_malloc(..., MALLOC_CAP_SPIRAM)" so I can't see why it is having ANY impact as its not being used?  I have had to park this while I work other tickets, but will need to come back to it if you have any ideas.

That's odd, I've used the ESP IDF OTA over HTTPS together with SPIRAM and haven't seen anything you describe. I guess there could be some interference as both Flash and SPIRAM use the same SPI bus, so a little bit of performance loss would be expected. But it should not be obvious and definitely not fail OTA.
